# Chrome ignores Windows host file

Tags: google-chrome, dns, localhost

I've setup a custom DNS on windows hosts file (*\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts*)

```
127.0.0.1       www.testdomain.localhost
```

Works on all my browser apart from Chrome (67.0.3396.99 64-bit)
What I tried so far:

```
chrome://net-internals/#sockets -> "Flush socket pools"
chrome://net-internals/#dns -> "Clear host cache"
CMD -> ipconfig /flushdns
```

**Crome history and cache clear (full clear).**
Removed prediction stuff from Chrome.

**PC restart**, **Chrome factory reset** and **I also called mum**.. still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found! Chrome seems to ignore the following extensions:

```
.dev
.localhost
.test
.example
```

and it works using **.local**

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Not sure why, but I can get to the local site using incognito mode.

Comment: Try disabling extensions. I disabled Wappalyzer and it started working for me.